# Jagged arrays and exceptions

Tags: c#, arrays, exception, jagged-arrays

Another jagged array question:

Currently with working jagged arrays in a class rather than in the Main(). With this jagged array I want to test my user input against a custom exception. Currently when i run the program, it creates the array right up to the last point where I want to populate the array and test that data against my exception. The exception is running despite the user input being correct. I'm not sure if the error is in my exception or if the error is my array.

NOTE: I know some of this may seem complicated, but for the sake of what I'm doing, it has to stay this way. Sorry :(

Class

```
class StudentGrades
{
    private char[][] grades;
    private double totalGpa;
    private int totalClasses;
    private int semesters;

    public StudentGrades ()
    {
        totalClasses = 0;
        SetSemesters(4);
        grades = new char [semesters][];
    }


    public void InputSemesters()
    {
        int x;
        int semestNum;
        bool check;
        do
        {
            check = false;
            try
            {
                for (int r = 0; r < grades.Length; r++)
                {
                    if (r == 0)
                    {
                        semestNum = 1;

                    }
                    else if (r == 1)
                    {
                        semestNum = 2;
                    }
                    else if (r == 2)
                    {
                        semestNum = 3;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        semestNum = 4;
                    }
                    Console.Write("How many courses were taken semster {0}? ", semestNum);
                    x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    CreateSemesters(r, x);  
                }
            }
            catch (System.FormatException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Problem with input.\n{0}\nTry again.", e.Message);
                check = true;
            }
        } while (check);

    }

    public void CreateSemesters(int sem, int numClasses)
    {
        grades[sem] = new char[numClasses];
        totalClasses += numClasses;
    }

    public void EnterGrades()
    {
        int semestNum;
        char letter;
        bool check;
        do
        {
            check = false;
            try
            {
                for (int r = 0; r < grades.Length; r++)
                {
                    if (r == 0)
                    {
                        semestNum = 1;

                    }
                    else if (r == 1)
                    {
                        semestNum = 2;
                    }
                    else if (r == 2)
                    {
                        semestNum = 3;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        semestNum = 4;
                    }
                    for (int c = 0; c < grades[r].Length; c++)
                    {

                        Console.Write("Enter the letter grade for class {0} of semester {1}: ", c + 1, semestNum); //the array creation works up to this part. So I know the array is creating but not storing data.
                        letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        letter = grades[r][c];
                        CheckLetterGrade(letter);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IncorrectLetterGradeException excepObj)
            {
                Console.Write("That is not an acceptable letter grade. Try Again. \n{0}", excepObj.Message);
                Console.WriteLine();
                check = true;
            }
        } while (check);
    }

    public void CheckLetterGrade(char G)
    {
        if (G != 'A' || G != 'B' || G != 'C' || G != 'D' || G != 'F')
        {
            IncorrectLetterGradeException excepObj = new IncorrectLetterGradeException("Not an acceptalbe letter grade of A-D or F");
            throw excepObj;
        }
    }
```

Main()

```
class UseStudentGrades
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StudentGrades student = new StudentGrades();
            // testing array functionality below
            student.InputSemesters();
            student.EnterGrades();
        }
    }
```

Exception

```
class IncorrectLetterGradeException :
                System.ApplicationException
    {
        public IncorrectLetterGradeException(string exceptionType)
            : base (exceptionType)
        {
            //empty body
        }
    }
```

UPDATE 1:
Currently trying this change to see if the exception stops prompting:

```
public void CheckLetterGrade(char G)
{
    bool gradeMatch = (G == 'A' || G == 'B' || G == 'C' || G == 'D' || G == 'F');        
    if (!gradeMatch)
    {
        IncorrectLetterGradeException excepObj = new IncorrectLetterGradeException("Not an acceptalbe letter grade of A-D or F");
        throw excepObj;
    }
}
```

And I'm getting this issue:

[Exception being thrown with correct user input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YAEY.png)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is possible to shrink your code to the bare minimum for your question. Who should read this all?

Comment: @maf-soft This has been edited to remove those items that do not pertain to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition

```
if (G != 'A' || G != 'B' || G != 'C' || G != 'D' || G != 'F')
```

will always be true. No matter what the character is in `G`, it will always not be equal to some of those letters. You should be using `&&`, the logical AND operator instead of `||` the logical OR operator.

```
if (G != 'A' && G != 'B' && G != 'C' && G != 'D' && G != 'F')
```

That way, for your exception to be thrown, the character in `G` will have to not equal any of your test letters.

Note also that your comparisons are case sensitive. Prior to comparing you may want to convert to uppercase:

```
char c = Char.ToUpper(G);
if (c != 'A' && c != 'B' && c != 'C' && c != 'D' && c != 'F')
```

There is a second problem in your code, in this section:

```
  letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  letter = grades[r][c];
  CheckLetterGrade(letter);
```

Here you assign letter from the character you parse from the user input. Then, you overwrite that value with a value you get from the grades array, thus losing completely the value the user entered. Then you check the value you got from grades (not the value you got from the user). I don't know what you're attempting to do with that middle line, so I'm not sure what correct code to suggest, but that is why the user entry is not really getting checked. I have a feeling though that you really want this:

```
  letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  grades[r][c] = letter;
  CheckLetterGrade(letter);
```

Comment: If you had a `List<char>` of valid grades the test could be made even more readable: `if (!validGrades.Contains(G))`

Comment: @BerinLoritsch - or even just a simple string `"ABCDF"`. I agree, there are things that could be improved.

Comment: Still getting the exception to prompt when I enter grade of A? Maybe I have the condition worded incorrectly? Exception should only prompt for letters that are not A-D or F.

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be ugly, otherwise I'd be happy to take the simplest route.

Comment: @ZLackLuster - I'd have to see what you changed it to that still didn't work. I think what I presented will work. However, note that if the user enters a lowercase character, that will also not match. You may want to covert their entry to uppercase to simplify your tests.

Comment: @hatchet I have added an update to my original post with code and photo.

Comment: @hatchet OH GOSH! Something so simple. Yup, I had my assignment order wrong. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As has already been pointed out, the problem is the complex OR statement.  There are several ways to improve the code so that it is more readable.

The following tests whether `G` *is* valid, and then tests the negation of that.

```
public void CheckLetterGrade(char G)
{
    bool isValidGrade = (G == 'A' || G == 'B' || G == 'C' || G == 'D' || G == 'F');
    if (!isValidGrade)
    {
        IncorrectLetterGradeException excepObj = new IncorrectLetterGradeException("Not an acceptalbe letter grade of A-D or F");
        throw excepObj;
    }
}
```

Next, if we want the test of the valid grade to be more concise we can do something like this:

```
bool isValidGrade = "ABCDF".Contains(G);
```

In C#, a string is a collection of characters so that test works well, and is probably easier to spot the problem.

Comment: The exception is still being thrown with this. I think the error exists within my population of the array, but I'm not sure.